# using mean with .SD and .SDcols in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, mean

I am writing a very simple function to summarize columns of data.tables.  I am passing one column at a time to the function, and then doing some diagnostics to figure out the options for summarization, and then doing the summarization.  I am doing this in data.table to allow for some very large datasets.

So, I am using `.SDcols` to pass in the column to summarize, and using functions on `.SD` in the `j` part of a data.table expression.  Since I am passing in one column at a time, I am not using lapply.  And what I am finding is that some functions work and others do not.  Below is a test dataset I am working with and the results I see:

```
dt <- data.table(
  a=1:10, 
  b=as.factor(letters[1:10]), 
  c=c(TRUE, FALSE), 
  d=runif(10, 0.5, 100), 
  e=c(0,1), 
  f=as.integer(c(0,1)), 
  g=as.numeric(1:10), 
  h=c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat5"))

mean(dt$a)
[1] 5.5

dt[, mean(.SD), .SDcols = "a"]

[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(.SD) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

dt[, sum(.SD), .SDcols = "a"]
[1] 55

dt[, max(.SD), .SDcols = "a"]
[1] 10

dt[, colMeans(.SD), .SDcols = "a"]
  a 
5.5 

dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = "a"]
     a
1: 5.5
```

Interestingly, `weighted.mean` gives the wrong answer (55, the sum) when I use `weighted.mean(.SD)` in j.  But when I use `lapply(.SD, weighted.mean)` in j, it gives the right answer (5.5, the mean).

I tried turning off data.table optimizations to see if it was the internal data.table mean function, but that didn't change things.

Maybe this is just a problem with using `mean()` on a list (which seems to be what `.SD` returns)?  I guess there is never a reason to NOT use the `lapply` paradigm with `.SD`?  It seems that only the `lapply` option returns a data.table.  The others seem to return vectors, except for colMeans which is returning something else (list?).

My main question is why `mean(.SD)` does not work.  And the corollary is whether .SD can be used in the absence of one of the apply functions.

Thanks.

Comment: `dt[, mean(.SD[[1]]), .SDcols=a]` `mean` works on a `vector`, the `.SD` is subset of `data.table` which is still not a vector.  You can get the same problem with `data.frame`. For example. `df1 <- data.frame(Col1=1:10); mean(df1[1])`, while `mean(df1[,1])` works

Comment: You should try code blocks (CTRL+K or pressing the code block button with highlighted text; or typing four spaces at the beginning of a line): http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @akrun:  that is interesting and makes sense.  The R error message seems misleading.  It suggests that it is a problem with the type of data (numeric or logical) and not the structure of the data.

Comment: @Frank:  thanks. that would have been much easier.  appreciate the help.

Comment: @MarkDanese  I remember an interesting discussion about this problem in R mailing list, but I couldn't find the link now.

Comment: @MarkDanese could you see if provided answer address or question? if not provide feedback, if it does accept it, so question will not remain unanswered. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the appropriate way of approaching what you want is to just use the standard syntax:

`dt[ , lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = "a"]`

Alternatively, you can pass a variable by name as follows:

```
col_to_pass = "a"
dt[ , mean(get(col_to_pass)) ]
```

Eventually, you can generalized this approach to multiple columns as follows:

```
col_to_pass = c("a", "d")
dt[ , lapply( mget(col_to_pass), mean) ]
```